# Load data from Oracle Linked server to SQL Server using OPENQUERY based on condition in SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am regularly loading data from Oracle linked server to SQL Server. For example (Plus using `MERGE` but lets try to make it simple)

```
Select ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, LastModifiedDate, CreatedDate  
from OPENQUERY(XYX, 'Select ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, LastModifiedDate, Createddate from TableA')
```

Using a SQL Server Job called Job- ABC.

Now, I want to make the load more efficient by only fetching the rows that have created or modified after the last success run of the SQL Server Job. The query to get the last successful job is below. Thank you @Nick Kavadias and @CodeCaster

```
DECLARE @job_id binary(16)

SELECT @job_id = job_id FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs WHERE (name = N'ABC')

SELECT TOP 1
    CONVERT(DATETIME, RTRIM(run_date))
    + ((run_time / 10000 * 3600) 
    + ((run_time % 10000) / 100 * 60) 
    + (run_time % 10000) % 100) / (86399.9964) AS run_datetime
    , *
FROM
    msdb..sysjobhistory sjh
WHERE
    sjh.step_id = 0 
    AND sjh.run_status = 1 
    AND sjh.job_id = @job_id
ORDER BY
    run_datetime DESC
```

Now I want to combine the two, to get the rows that have modified and created after the last job run. Can someone please help me.

Comment: It feels like you're asking  if you can parametrise a call to `OPENQUERY`. If thet is the case, the answer is you can't; `OPENQUERY` expects a literal. You would have to likely use dynamic SQL to achieve what I *think* you are after.

Comment: @Larnu Thank you. Any idea how that looks like?

Comment: Not when i don't know what the columns you want to filter on the remote query are, @DataMan. You're just doing a `SELECT * FROM Tablename` at the moment, so I don't even know what the columns *might* be called.

Comment: @Larnu Please Assume, ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC

Comment: That doesn't help me, I'm afraid.